# winapi - rich edit control and vertical text layout (single line)

Tags: winapi

I have noticed that a text in the rich edit control (only a single line) is not centered vertically. A space between a text and a top border edge is larger than a space between a text and a botttom border edge. It is especially [visible](https://ibb.co/sbBRG50) when a rich edit control height is only a little bit bigger that a text height.  PARAMFORMAT only allow to set a horizontal alignment. How to set a vertical alignment / top-bottom margins ?

**Edit:**

This way I get PARAMFORMAT2 structure:

```
PARAFORMAT2 pf;
ZeroMemory(&pf, sizeof(pf));
pf.cbSize = sizeof(pf);
SendMessage(hwndRichEdit1, EM_GETPARAFORMAT, 0, (LPARAM)&pf);
```

dySpaceBefore is already initially set to 0 and the effect you can see on the attached screenshot.

I use Visual Studio 2017, MSFTEDIT_CLASS is defined in Richedit.h as    L"RICHEDIT50W"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a [Rich Edit 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-rich-edit-controls#rich-edit-version-20) control, you can use the `PARAFORMAT2` [structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/ns-richedit-paraformat2), which has the option to set the space before the text.

You haven't added a language tag, but here's how you would do it in `C` (see also the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setparaformat) for `EM_SETPARAFORMAT`):

```c
//...
PARAFORMAT2 pf2;
pf2.cbSize = sizeof(PARAFORMAT2);
pf2.dwMask = PFM_SPACEBEFORE; // Of course, you can OR in other bits/options to set!
pf2.dySpaceBefore = 0;        // Will align to the top; use a small +ve value, if you prefer
SendMessage(hWndEdit, EM_SETPARAFORMAT, 0, (LPARAM)&pf2);
//...
```

To get vertically centred text is bit more work, as you will need to get the height of the text (using `GetTextExtent`) and the height of the control's client rectangle, then use a 'space before' value of (client_height - text_height)/2.

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation. (I *may* even be able to offer you code in another language.)

Comment: @Irbis OK - this is just a guess, but maybe try setting the edit control's style to include `ES_MULTILINE` (even though I *know* you only actually have one line): maybe the `PARAFORMAT(2)` doesn't work on single-line controls?

Comment: ES_MULTILINE doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue like this snapshot shows:

[image]

There seems no feature supported for vertical alignment center. I've submit a feature request internally.

**A workaround** is using [EM_SETRECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setrect) which can move up text area via limiting rectangle into which the control draws the text. The following snapshots show its effects:

[image]

[image]

Then you can use it to adjust the text to display it in center between top and bottom.

Code example:

```
   HWND hwndEdit = CreateWindowEx(
       0,
       MSFTEDIT_CLASS,
       TEXT("EDIT"),
       WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
       20,
       20,
       100,
       32,
       hWnd,
       NULL,
       hInst,
       NULL);

   RECT rect;

   SendMessage(hwndEdit, EM_GETRECT, 0, (LPARAM)&rect);

   rect.top -= 2;
   rect.bottom -= 2;

   SendMessage(hwndEdit, EM_SETRECT, 1, (LPARAM)&rect);
```